# Disable colors in code coverage output from PHPUnit

Tags: php, regex, phpunit, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to automate testing for a little PHP project of mine, it works well so far, the only thing I could not get to work is the code coverage report.

In Gitlab-Ci there is the option `Test coverage parsing`, which accepts a regex.
So far so good, I found a regex at http://jarretbyrne.com/2015/04/gitlab-ci-phpunit-test-coverage-parsing/ : `^\s*Lines:\s*\d+.\d+\%`

But as the comment says: it doesn't work with colors enabled.
`PHPUnit` has the command line switch `--colors-[always|never|auto]` but this option only applies to the normal output.

How can I turn off colors for `--coverage-text`? Can I use another regex?

**Edit:**

There is an open issue at https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1771

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running phpunit like that now to strip all colors from the output:

`php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --coverage-text | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g"`

Answer (score 3):

You can just set `--colors=never` and they'll be disabled. It really works with colors previously enabled in the xml file (I've just tested it), try it:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never
```

So I guess that issue was already fixed :)